# How to get value of a specific node from and xml based on specific condition sql

Tags: sql, xml

I have a XML where i want to fetch the value of scheduleName where GrantName=Grant 2 and Scheduleid=003.

I am also joining the result with a table which contains client information. For every client id i want to fetch the schedule name as mentioned.

Below is the sample XML which i am using.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (XmlCol xml)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
('<option>
            <OptionName>Option 1</OptionName>
            <grant>
                    <GrantName>Grant 1</GrantName>
                            <schedules>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID id=001></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName>s1</scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>1/1/2018</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID id=002></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName>s2</scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>2/1/2018</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID id=003></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName>s3</scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>3/1/2018</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                            </schedules>
            </grant>
            <grant>
                            <GrantName>Grant 2</GrantName>
                            <schedules>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID id=001></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName>s1</scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>1/1/2019</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID id=002></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName>s2</scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>2/1/2019</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID id=003></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName>s3</scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>3/1/2019</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                            </schedules>
            </grant>
            <grant>
                            <GrantName>Grant 3</GrantName>
                            <schedules>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID id=001></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName>s1</scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>1/1/2020</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID id=002></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName>s2</scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>2/1/2020</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID id=003></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName>s3</scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>3/1/2020</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                            </schedules>
            </grant>
        </option>'
)
```

Please help me with the query in sql

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (XmlCol xml)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
('<Fact>
  <ID Value="d71a58e9-6e9c-4c2b-9a6a-76e066978af4" />
  <AssetAllocationModel>
    <ModelPortfolios>
      <ModelPortfolio>
        <Name>Asset Pres</Name>
        <ModelPortfolioID Value="assetpres" />
        <AssetClassMix>
          <Percent>0.1000</Percent>
          <AssetClassID Value="largegrowth" />
          <Value />
        </AssetClassMix>
        <AssetClassMix>
          <Percent>0.0500</Percent>
          <AssetClassID Value="largevalue" />
          <Value />
        </AssetClassMix>
        <AssetClassMix>
          <Percent>0.2500</Percent>
          <AssetClassID Value="investbond" />
          <Value />
        </AssetClassMix>
        <AssetClassMix>
          <Percent>0.5000</Percent>
          <AssetClassID Value="shortermbond" />
          <Value />
        </AssetClassMix>
        <AssetClassMix>
          <Percent>0.1000</Percent>
          <AssetClassID Value="cash" />
          <Value />
        </AssetClassMix>
        <Risk>0</Risk>
      </ModelPortfolio>
              <ModelPortfolio>
                     <Name>Income</Name>
                     <ModelPortfolioID Value="income" />
                     <AssetClassMix>
                           <Percent>0.3000</Percent>
                           <AssetClassID Value="investbond" />
                           <Value />
                     </AssetClassMix>
                     <AssetClassMix>
                           <Percent>0.3500</Percent>
                           <AssetClassID Value="shortermbond" />
                           <Value />
                     </AssetClassMix>
                     <AssetClassMix>
                           <Percent>0.0500</Percent>
                           <AssetClassID Value="cash" />
                           <Value />
                     </AssetClassMix>
                     <Risk>0</Risk>
              </ModelPortfolio>
       <ModelPortfolio>
        <Name>Agg Growth</Name>
        <ModelPortfolioID Value="aggrgrowth" />
        <AssetClassMix>
          <Percent>0.1000</Percent>
          <AssetClassID Value="internat" />
          <Value />
        </AssetClassMix>
        <AssetClassMix>
          <Percent>0.1000</Percent>
          <AssetClassID Value="emerging" />
          <Value />
        </AssetClassMix>
        <AssetClassMix>
          <Percent>0.0300</Percent>
          <AssetClassID Value="highyldbond" />
          <Value />
        </AssetClassMix>
        <AssetClassMix>
          <Percent>0.0200</Percent>
          <AssetClassID Value="cash" />
          <Value />
        </AssetClassMix>
        <Risk>0</Risk>
      </ModelPortfolio>
    </ModelPortfolios>
  </AssetAllocationModel>
  <AttestationDate />
</Fact>'
)

select * from @tbl

SELECT top 1 t.x.value('(./Percent)[1]','decimal(10,2)')*100 FROM(
       SELECT t.x.query('(./AssetClassMix)') as 'AssetClassMix'
       FROM @tbl rec
       CROSS APPLY rec.XmlCol.nodes ('/Fact/AssetAllocationModel/ModelPortfolios/ModelPortfolio')  t(x)
       WHERE t.x.value('(./ModelPortfolioID/@Value)[1]','varchar(max)') = 'aggrgrowth'
) a
CROSS APPLY a.AssetClassMix.nodes('/AssetClassMix') t(x)
WHERE t.x.value('(./AssetClassID/@Value)[1]','varchar(max)')='cash'
```

This is what i am using to get the value. Is there any other way without using CROSS APPLY. Since in PROD there is huge data, CROSS APPLY is very heavy.